# How to plot a Spectrogram with very small values?

Tags: python, matplotlib, audio, spectrogram

I am using `librosa` to read a sound file and `matplotlib.pyplot.specgram` to plot its spectrogram and return its frequency and time bins in `spectrum`.

Code:

```
import librosa
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import specgram

filepath = r"1301524547165114.wav"

f, sr = librosa.load(filepath)
spectrum, freqs, t, im = specgram(np.array(f), Fs=sr, noverlap=2**7, NFFT=2**8)
print(spectrum.shape)
plt.suptitle("Figure 1: Spectrogram")
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Output:
`(129, 347)` 
[image]

Here spectrogram looks good, but when I plot it using `spectrum`, most of the graph is dark because most of the values in `spectrum` are very small.

Code:

```
def print_image(image, title):
    plt.imshow(image, origin="lower")
    plt.title(title)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.show()

print_image(spectrum, "Figure 2: Spectrogram")
```

Output:
[image]

Here's the audio file I used: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WMvOqsSNllgX5R_hUzhHm0gYopYnbZGZ

Why `matplotlib.pyplot.specgram` is able to plot it properly?
How can I plot it using data (`spectrum`) I received from `matplotlib.pyplot.specgram`.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the data is plotted on a dB scale. So you would need to take the logarithm or use a `LogNorm` when plotting this yourself. I also think something similar has already been asked before, so it would make sense to state in how far those question do not help.

Comment: Thanks. I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17494185/ but it is not for spectrogram, so I am not able to fix my problem using it.

Comment: I guess the now marked duplicate shows the problem and the solution in very much detail; no need to have another question on that topic. In case however this does not solve the issue, clearly state in how far that wouldn't be the case. Btw. I found this by typing `[matplotlib] *specgram*` in the search field above. As [ask] states, always search and share your research.